# JQuery weather app - print text w if statements?

Tags: jquery, if-statement, jquery-plugins, yahoo-weather-api

I'm new to jQuery, and I'm trying to write a web app to tell you the weather in words (as well as numbers.) I'm using the simpleweather jQuery plugin, which uses [Yahoo's weather info](https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/documentation.html#codes). The docs show a "weather code" associated with each "type" of weather.

I'd like to implement an if statement that would print a custom string of text depending on the given weather code.

My instincts say something like this:

```
if(weather.code = 0) {
html += '<p>'"There's a tornado!"'</p>';
}
```

But I also figure I should create a function that holds the associated strings, so that my code isn't just a huge mess.

```
function(printWeather) {
if(weather.code = 0) {
"There's a tornado!"
}
```

and then in my loadWeather function include something like:

```
html += '<p>'+printWeather+'</p>';
```

Here's my loadWeather function as it is now:

```
function loadWeather(location, woeid) {
 $.simpleWeather({
  location: location,
  woeid: woeid,
  unit: 'f',
  success: function(weather) {
   if(weather.temp > 75) {
    $('body').animate({backgroundColor: '#F7AC57'}, 1500);
  } else {
    $('body').animate({backgroundColor: '#0091c2'}, 1500);
  }
  html = '<h2><i class="icon-'+weather.code+'"></i> '+weather.temp+'&deg;'+weather.units.temp+'</h2>';
  html += '<ul><li>'+weather.city+', '+weather.region+'</li>';
  html += '<li class="currently">'+weather.currently+'</li>';
  html += '<li>'+weather.alt.temp+'&deg;C</li></ul>';  

  $("#weather").html(html);
},
error: function(error) {
  $("#weather").html('<p>'+error+'</p>');
}
});
```

Would appreciate any guidance! Thank you.

EDIT: Here's my code now, with my attempt at writing a printWeather function - but it's not working.

```
function printWeather(code) {
 $.simpleweather({
  code: code,
  success: function(weather) {
   if(weather.code >= 0 && weather.code <=2) {
    html += ("<p>BLAH BLAH</p>");
  } else if (weather.code >= 3 && weather.code <=4) {
    html += ("<p>BLAH2</p>");
  } 
 }
 })
}

function loadWeather(location, woeid) {
 $.simpleWeather({
 location: location,
 woeid: woeid,
 unit: 'f',
 success: function(weather) {
  html = '<h2><i class="icon-'+weather.code+'"></i></h2>';
  html += '<ul><li>'+weather.city+', '+weather.region+'</li>';
  html += '<li class="currently">'+weather.currently+'</li>';
  html += '<li>'+weather.temp+'&deg;F / '+weather.alt.temp+'&deg;C</li></ul>'; 

  //print current weather code (for testing purposes)
  html += '<p>'+weather.code+'</p>'
  // html += '<p>'+printWeather(weather.code+)'</p>'

  $("#weather").html(html);
},
error: function(error) {
  $("#weather").html('<p>'+error+'</p>');
}
});
}
```

I'm not sure how to call the printWeather function properly. Or if that's even correct.

Comment: What's the issue here that you need help with?

Comment: Basically, I'm just not sure how to implement the if statements. Should I create a new function (printWeather, in this example) that has the if statements in it?  With something like:

    if(weather.code >= 0 && weather.code <=2) {
        html += ("<p>blah blah blah</p>");

and at the end of my loadWeather function, how would I implement the printWeather function?

Comment: How many potential codes are there?

Comment: 47... But I'm grouping them so 0-2 will have the same associated string. But it's going to be a really long if statement.

Comment: Maybe create a JSON object of all the codes and what they mean and then query that each time. Might be the simplest.